# mini-css-extract-plugin: After extracting the file, error "Missed semicolon" occurring of error-free css file

Tags: css, webpack, mini-css-extract-plugin

Here is the SyntaxError:

[The screeshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RxMO.png)

In the below [name].module.css, there are no semi-colon issue present.
Here is my module.css file:

```
/* Groningen */

.groningen p,
.groningen h3,
.groningen a:hover,
.groningen li:hover,
.groningen h4 a:hover {
  color: #017363 !important;
}

.groningen button {
  background-color: #017363 !important;
  border: #017363 !important;
}

.groningen .thumbnail-inner-2::before {
  background-color: #017363 !important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#017363 10%, #000000 100%) !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #017363 !important;
}

/* Rotterdam */

.rotterdam p,
.rotterdam h3,
.rotterdam li:hover,
.rotterdam a:hover,
.rotterdam h4 a:hover {
  color: #004ab0 !important;
}

.rotterdam button,
.rotterdam button {
  background-color: #004ab0 !important;
  border: #004ab0 !important;
}

.rotterdam .thumbnail-inner-2::before {
  background-color: #004ab0 !important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#004ab0 10%, #000000 100%) !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #004ab0 !important;
}

/* leeuwarden */

.leeuwarden p,
.leeuwarden h3,
.leeuwarden a:hover,
.leeuwarden li:hover,
.leeuwarden h4 a:hover {
  color: #ff914d !important;
}

.leeuwarden button {
  background-color: #ff914d !important;
  border: #ff914d !important;
}

.leeuwarden .thumbnail-inner-2::before {
  background-color: #ff914d !important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ff914d 10%, #000000 100%) !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #ff914d !important;
}
```

Here is the webpack.common.js

```
const paths = require('./paths');
const path = require('path');

const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: [paths.src + '/index.js'],
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),

    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: paths.public + '/assets',
          to: 'assets',
        },
      ],
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      favicon: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/favicon.ico'),
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/index.html'), // template file
      filename: 'index.html', // output file
    }),
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    fallback: {
      fs: false,
      assert: require.resolve('assert'),
      buffer: false,
      console: false,
      constants: require.resolve('constants-browserify'),
      crypto: false,
      domain: false,
      events: false,
      http: false,
      https: false,
      os: false,
      path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
      punycode: false,
      process: false,
      querystring: false,
      stream: false,
      string_decoder: false,
      sys: false,
      timers: false,
      tty: false,
      url: false,
      util: require.resolve('util'),
      vm: false,
      zlib: false,
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: ['babel-loader'] },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: ['html-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: { url: false },
          },
          {
            loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              mimetype: 'application/font-woff',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'images',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Here is webpack.prod.js

```
const path = require('path');
const paths = require('./paths');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: false,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, paths.build),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash].bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'styles/[name].[contenthash].css',
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: { url: false },
          },
          {
            loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true, // Ensure sourceMap is set to a boolean value
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true, // Ensure sourceMap is set to a boolean value
            },
          },
        ],
        sideEffects: true,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
        sideEffects: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: 'runtime',
    },
  },
});
```

What is the fix? As the code is working fine in Webpack dev environment but not in prod.

Expecting to know the fix that where should I put a semi-colon??

Comment: Can you share your complete Webpack configuration? You can edit your question again and add it.

Comment: What debugging have you tried? As it seems to be in the region of .thumbnail-inner-2 perhaps start by removing that and seeing what happens for example.

Comment: The debugging I have tried is like changing the Webpack configs and CSS file, but I didn't get any results @AHaworth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have conflicting loaders being loaded in production for `*.scss` and `*.css` files. It works in **development mode** because, you are using only `webpack.common.js` file. In production, you are merging using `webpack-merge` which will produce following output for `module.rules`

```
{
  rules: [
    { test: /\.(js|jsx)$/ },
    { test: /\.html$/ },
    { test: /\.scss$/ },
    { test: /\.css$/ },
    { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/ },
    {
      test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
  
    },
    { test: /\.scss$/ },
    { test: /\.css$/ }
  ]
}
```

If you simply comment out CSS loader from `webpack.common.js` file, then it would work for production.

```
// Comment this out.
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
},
```

There are couple of ways to solve it. The most obvious being the use of environment flag/variable to conditionally configure the right loader. The `mini-css-extract-plugin` already has a [good example](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin?tab=readme-ov-file#examples) of showing this.

The second option is to have three files and then use the common configuration in each of the other file:

- `common.js` - Common configuration.
- `dev.js` - Dev only configuration where you use `style-loader` for CSS.
- `prod.js` - Prod configuration where you use `mini-css-extract-plugin` loader.

> On a side note, your configuration is not complex enough to warrant the use of something like `webpack-merge`. Just your plain-old JavaScript with object spread and destructuring, and you should be good to go.